# How do I drop a pin at location on React Native MapView press?

Tags: react-native

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/mapview.html

I am looking for an example on how to press on the map to create an annotation that location.

I know how to add the annotation, but do not know how to get the coordinates of where I just pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything about an `onPress` event in the react-native `MapView` docs or code - But found this on github: https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps - looks pretty good and has an `onPress` event which returns the coordinates (https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps#mapview-events)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was a huge pain to set up considering I am new to xcode and the rnpm link breaks the ios build, but after going through some of the Github issues and struggling for a few hours, I was able to refer to this example https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DefaultMarkers.js to get the drop pin functionality working.

Answer (score 1):

I use the `onPress` method on the `MapView` like this:

```react
class DefaultMarkers extends React.Component {

     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            markers: [],
         };
     }

     onMapPress(e) {
         this.setState({
            markers: [
                ...this.state.markers,
                {
                   coordinate: e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
                   key: id++,
                },
             ],
          }
       );
     }

     render() {
         return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView
                   style={styles.map}
                   onPress={e => this.onMapPress(e)}
                >
                   {this.state.markers.map(marker => (
                       <Marker
                          key={marker.key}
                          coordinate={marker.coordinate}
                       />
                   ))}
                </MapView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Check out the [full example](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/DefaultMarkers.js) full example on the [react-native-maps github](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [Gesture Responder System](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system.html) docs.

The easiest way is to wrap something into for example `<TouchableOpacity />` and you can grab the coordinates in the `onPress` event handler:

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.locationX)}>
  {/* ... */}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Everything is quite nicely explained in the docs above, for more advanced gestures handling look into [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html).